# What is file.sc extension

Tags: html, web, file-extension

What is file extension for file.sc found in www.webmail.com/file.sc. I never heard of this file in web is it a server file just like asp.net,php?

Answer (score 3):

its a supercollider file:

http://www.audiosynth.com/

Comment: @purter Thanks Porter for the link

Comment: @pOrter can supercollider be used for website coding

Comment: Ok Porter Thanks for the link